# JOIN for a table 2 times

Tags: mysql, sql, database

In my MySQL database, I have tables: `group`, `profile` and `profile_titles`.
Here is the structure of table `group`:

```
+----------+----------------+------------+
| group_id | title          | profile_id |
|        1 | Group Title 1  |          1 |
|        2 | Group Title 2  |          1 |
|        3 | Group Title 3  |          2 |
|        4 | Group Title 4  |          2 |
|      ... | Group Title 1  |        ... |
|       20 | Group Title 20 |         12 |
+----------+----------------+------------+
```

`profile_id` links to FK in table `profile`:

```
+------------+------------------+
| profile_id | profile_title_id |
+------------+------------------+
|          1 |                1 |
|          2 |                2 |
|          3 |                3 |
|        ... |              ... |
|         11 |                1 |
|         12 |                5 |
+------------+------------------+
```

`profile_title_id` links to FK in table `profile_title`:

```
+------------------+-----------------------+
| profile_title_id | title                 |
+------------------+-----------------------+
|                1 | Profile Title 1       |
|                2 | Profile Title 2       |
|                3 | Profile Title 3       |
|                4 | Profile Title 4       |
|              ... | ...                   |
|               10 | Profile Title 10      |
+------------------+-----------------------+
```

I have trouble with `JOIN`.
Here is what i *want* to get as result:

```
+----------+----------------+-------------------+-------------------+
| group_id | title          | profile_title_id  | profile_title     |
+----------+----------------+-------------------+-------------------+
|        1 | Group Title 1  |                 1 |   Profile Title 1 |
|        2 | Group Title 2  |                 1 |   Profile Title 1 |
|        3 | Group Title 3  |                 2 |   Profile Title 2 |
|        4 | Group Title 4  |                 2 |   Profile Title 2 |
|      ... |         ...    |               ... |               ... |
|       20 | Group Title 20 |                 5 |   Profile Title 5 |
+----------+----------------+-------------------+-------------------+
```

But I am only get first 3 columns of what I want to get (`group_id`, `title` and `profile_title_id`). How can I add `profile_title` to my result? My query now:

```
SELECT
    `group`.`group_id`,
    `group`.`title`,
    `profile`.`profile_title_id`
FROM `group`
LEFT JOIN `profile` ON `group`.`profile_id` = `profile`.`profile_id`
```

I was trying this query, but it returns an error (#1066 - Not unique table/alias: 'profile'):

```
SELECT
    `group`.`group_id`,
    `group`.`title`,
    `profile`.`profile_title_id`,
    `profile_title`.`title`
FROM `group`
LEFT JOIN `profile` ON `group`.`profile_id` = `profile`.`profile_id`
LEFT JOIN `profile` ON `group`.`profile_id` = `profile`.`profile_title_id`
```

Would love any suggestions, thanks!

Comment: you don't have profile_titles in your query

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you're joining profile twice when you should be joining on profile_title in the second left join:

```
SELECT
    `group`.`group_id`,
    `group`.`title`,
    `profile`.`profile_title_id`,
    `profile_title`.`title`
FROM `group`
LEFT JOIN `profile` ON `group`.`profile_id` = `profile`.`profile_id`
LEFT JOIN `profile_title` ON `profile`.`profile_title_id` = `profile_title`.`profile_title_id`
```

As for the error in your question - When joining the same table more than once you must [alias](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_alias.asp) the tables in order to distinguish between them.

note you can alias any table you're selecting from, basically it allows for a "shortcut" when referencing the table, or a way to uniquely identify tables in your query should there be multiple by the same name.

table aliases can be written like:

```
select *
from 'group' as g
```

in the above query, you could reference columns by `g` rather than `group`.

Comment: @vkp thanks, i was looking at the error message by itself rather than the logic error in the query.

Comment: Thank you very much! It solved my problem. Defenitly will look into aliases.

Answer (score 1):

Please try something like:

```
SELECT
    `group`.`group_id`,
    `group`.`title`,
    `profile`.`profile_title_id`,
    `profile_title`.`title`
FROM `group`
LEFT JOIN `profile` ON `group`.`profile_id` = `profile`.`profile_id`
LEFT JOIN `profile_title` ON `profile`.`profile_title_id ` = `profile_title`.`profile_title_id`
```